# Pandoc: Split TOC in SubTOC's

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am using the pandoc-uikit (https://github.com/diversen/pandoc-uikit) to generate a HTML-Output. Using:

`$if(toc)$
 $toc$
 $endif$`

generates the table of content, as it should do. However, I do not need a single TOC, but rather split it into a couple of SUB-TOCs to add something like a paragraph-headline, eg:

```
Paragraph 1:
 SUBTOC 1
Paragraph 2:
 SUBTOC 2:
...
Paragraph X:
 SUBTOC X
```

I am not able to reconfigure the .md-files to make it work. Thus, the template or the request needs to be adjusted (or both). But I am not able to figure out how that works in a pure automate way.

Every help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Florian

Comment: probably you'll have to post-process the HTML to do that...

Comment: That's what I have done by now with a Python-Script. I created a SubTOC-template which then generates a couple of SubTOCs and merges these together to a TOC, looking like the given example. Afterwards I inject the the new TOC into the given template by pandoc-uikit. But this way seems pretty hacky - don't know if there is a better solution.